# Regex: Retrieve values from one of the two HTML tags.

Tags: html, regex

I'm using OutWit Hub to scrape company names from a website.

In some pages, the HTML tag is like this:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold;">COMPANY NAME</p>
```

while in other pages:

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">COMPANY NAME</span>
```

All the pages use one of the above two options, but never both.

If you're not familiar with OutWit Hub, it works by asking for the marker before, and the marker after the piece of information you want.

I'm trying to create a Regex that will retrieve the company name, regardless of which one of those markers is used whether before or after.

So far I have tried this for the 'before' tag, but it doesn't work:

```
/[<p style="font-weight: bold;">]|[<p>Name of Company: <span style="font-weight: bold;">]/
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Zoltan: Please don't bother posting that link without giving context.  That link is funny only to people who understand why regex parsing is bad.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Hah, not to worry – a more effective way of getting the message across than tirelessly explaining for the umpteenth time! Thanks for the advice though, managed to sort it a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the square brackets (`[...]`), these are used to specify a [character class or character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), not a sequence of characters.

```
/<p style="font-weight: bold;">|<p>Name of Company: <span style="font-weight: bold;">/
```

For help understanding and debugging regular expressions, check out [Regexpr](http://www.regexper.com/).

However, as others have commented, regular expressions aren't the most reliable approach to parsing HTML. For example, how do you know that there will never be any other paragraphs or spans on the page with a style of `font-weight: bold`?

If you know C# then the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a useful library for parsing HTML. It may be overkill for your needs though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regular expression & take the 2nd Group data to get the Company Name:

```
^(<p style="font-weight: bold;">|<span style="font-weight: bold;">)(.*)(</p>|</span>)
```